# Submission of a nullable datetime is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, datetime, nullable

***[How to save a TimeOfDay? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20614295/how-to-save-a-timeofday) haven't an answer and this present post it's about a specific problem an not a general question like that post***

I'm trying save/submit a Date and a TimeOfDay of a specific **DateTime (nullable)** variable but when it arrives to my controller its value is **always null** even user insert other values. How can I solve this?

**My visual objective:**

[image]

**My view:**

```
<div style="display:inline-block">
            <div class="editor-label">
                Initial date:
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.StartDate.Value.Date, new { type = "date" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartDate)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div style="display:inline-block">
            <div class="editor-label">
                Initial hour:
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.StartDate.Value.TimeOfDay, new { type = "time" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartDate)
            </div>
        </div>
```

**My model:**

```
[DataType(DataType.Date), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
```

**My model binding** (from [this link](http://devblog.lundy.us/2010/09/28/date-time-picker-asp-net-mvc-jquery-part-1/) what is great but don't work to nullable dates and I don't know why)**:**

```
public class DateTimeModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    private Nullable<T> GetA<T>(ModelBindingContext bindingContext, string key) where T : struct
    {
        if (bindingContext.ValueProvider.ContainsPrefix(bindingContext.ModelName))
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(key)) key = bindingContext.ModelName;
            else key = bindingContext.ModelName + "." + key;
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(key)) return null;

        ValueProviderResult value;

        value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(key);
        bindingContext.ModelState.SetModelValue(key, value);

        if (value == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        Nullable<T> retVal = null;
        try
        {
            retVal = (Nullable<T>)value.ConvertTo(typeof(T));
        }
        catch (Exception) { }

        return retVal;
    }

    public override object BindModel(
        ControllerContext controllerContext,
        ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("bindingContext");

        // Check for a simple DateTime value with no suffix
        DateTime? dateTimeAttempt = GetA<DateTime>(bindingContext, "");
        if (dateTimeAttempt != null)
        {
            return dateTimeAttempt.Value;
        }

        // Check for separate Date / Time fields
        DateTime? dateAttempt = GetA<DateTime>(bindingContext, "Date");
        DateTime? timeAttempt = GetA<DateTime>(bindingContext, "TimeOfDay");

        //If we got both parts, assemble them!
        if (dateAttempt != null && timeAttempt != null)
        {
            return new DateTime(dateAttempt.Value.Year,
                dateAttempt.Value.Month,
                dateAttempt.Value.Day,
                timeAttempt.Value.Hour,
                timeAttempt.Value.Minute,
                timeAttempt.Value.Second);
        }

        //Only got one half? Return as much as we have!
        return dateAttempt ?? timeAttempt;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your interface says dd-mm-aaaa (annum?), but your data DisplayFormat attribute says dd/MM/yy. Could be what's causing your trouble?

Comment: I'm sorry but where you saw dd-mm-aaaa (annum?)? However, I commented DataType requirer line but my datetime model still arriving null to my controller

Comment: In the text/date box. The screenshot.

Comment: Oh ok. @Twon-ha I don't believe that's the problem because the date format is only checked when I check if `Model.IsValid` on my controller and the problem is now my `Model` is arriving to controller with a null `StartDate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the lack of one **?** on the call of my ModelBinder on `Global.asax`. So its code changed to:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(DateTime?), new Models.DateTimeModelBinder());
```

and the changes [Richard Deeming](https://stackoverflow.com/users/124386/richard-deeming) suggests should be done too:

```
if (dateAttempt == null && timeAttempt == null)
{
    dateAttempt = GetA<DateTime>(bindingContext, "Value.Date");
    timeAttempt = GetA<DateTime>(bindingContext, "Value.TimeOfDay");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The binder is looking for two post values called `StartDate.Date` and `StartDate.TimeOfDay`; however, the `TextBoxFor` method will have named these controls `StartDate.Value.Date` and `StartDate.Value.TimeOfDay` instead.

Try adding code to your binder to check for these names:

```
DateTime? dateAttempt = GetA<DateTime>(bindingContext, "Date");
DateTime? timeAttempt = GetA<DateTime>(bindingContext, "TimeOfDay");

if (dateAttempt == null && timeAttempt == null)
{
    dateAttempt = GetA<DateTime>(bindingContext, "Value.Date");
    timeAttempt = GetA<DateTime>(bindingContext, "Value.TimeOfDay");
}
```

Comment: I really think you're right, but this still doesn't work, my `StartDate` still arriving null

Comment: @Ninita: Have a look at the generated HTML to double-check the input names. If they look OK, try using [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) to capture the request and see what the POST data looks like.